# How does Angular.js handle event bindings such as "ng-click"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How does Angular.js handle event bindings such as "ng-click"?

If I inspect the HTML output in the DOM using Chrome Dev Tools, I only see 2 classes added to elements which have "ng-click" directives, "ng-scope" and "ng-binding". How does Angular bind to the DOM to intercept these? Does it attach to the topmost element, and keep a big object in memory mapping events to DOM elements they are registered to, and make use of event bubbling? or something else?

Answer (score 5):

AngularJS does dirty-checking, every time a AngularJS finds a directive it will set a $watch to look at changes.

The $watch list is a set of expressions which may have changed since last iteration. If a change is detected then the $watch function is called which typically updates the DOM with the new value. Once the Angular $digest loop finishes the execution leaves the Angular and JavaScript context. This is followed by the browser re-rendering the DOM to reflect any changes.

To say it simple, there is a mechanisme that creates a, list of directives that need binding, during the $digest loop the list will be checked on changes if there is a change the browser re-renders the DOM and it will be reflected into the browser.

This is a very short explanation, you can find more here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime

Answer (score 0):

The ng-[eventname]-directives works by doing a `element.bind`, where element is a jQuery/[jqLite element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element). This [bind method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) works by calling a element.addEventListener (at least in Chrome). You will not see that eventlistener by inspecting the DOM.

Comment: You can actually see the event listeners at the bottom of the right panel in dev tools under "Event Listeners"